# If $(\mathbb{R}^2,+,\cdot)$ is a field, then there exists $u\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $u^2=-e$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, field-theory, self-learning

Suppose that $(\mathbb{R}^2,+,\cdot)$ is a field such that $(\alpha z)\cdot (\beta\omega)=(\alpha\beta)(z\cdot\omega)$, where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $z,\omega\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that there exists $u\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $u^2=-e$, where $e$ is the identity for $\cdot$.

My thought: given the identity element $e$, we can find $u\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\{e,u\}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. There exist two unique reals $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that $u^2=\lambda e+\mu u$. If $\lambda=0$, then $u^2=\mu u$, that is, $u=\mu e$, which is not possible, so $\lambda\neq 0$. This shows that $e$ is a linear combination of $u$ and $u^2$, therefore $\{u^2,u\}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

How could I proceed now?

Comment: Consider elements of the form $au+be$ and show that some of them have square $-e$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez So I have $(au+be)^2=a^2u^2+2abu+b^2e=a^2(\lambda e+\mu u)+2abu+b^2e=(a^2\lambda +b^2)e+(a^2\mu+2ab)u$. If that is $-e$, then $a(\mu+2b)=0$ and $a^2\lambda+b^2=-1$. If $a=0$, then $b^2=-1$, which is impossible. Then $\mu+2b=0$, that is, $b=-\mu/2$ and $a^2=(-1-\mu^2/4)/\lambda$. Thus, if $\lambda<0$, for those $a$ and $b$ there are elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose square is $-e$. I don't see how to solve the question yet.

Comment: Hint: Show that the square of the element $w=(u-\mu e/2)$ is a real multiple of $e$. Why does that multiple need to be negative ($\leftarrow$ this is the difficult step)? Then scale that multiple to $-1$ by considering the square of $\alpha w$ for a suitable choice of $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If $w=u-\mu e/2$, then $w^2=u^2-\mu u+(\mu^2/4)e=(\lambda +\mu^2/4)e$. Now I want to prove that $\lambda<-\mu^2/4$. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: You showed that $u$ is a root of polynomial $X^2 -\mu X -\lambda$. Essentially, Jyrki's hint is to use quadratic formula (completing the squares). You do know when roots of quadratic are real by examining discriminant. In this case, discriminant will tell you whether $u$ is equal to some $\alpha e$ or not.

Comment: What Ennar said. If $\lambda+\mu^2/4$ is $\ge0$, can you arrive at a contradiction by finding square roots other than $\pm w$ to it? Remember that you are supposed to get a field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think I got it. We have $u^2-\mu u -\lambda e=0$. Completing squares, $w^2=(\mu^2/4+\lambda)e$, where $w=u-(\mu/2)e$. Suppose by contradiction that $\mu^2/4+\lambda>0$. Then we can consider $v=+\sqrt{\mu^2/4+\lambda}\,e$. As $w^2=v^2$, $w=\pm v$, therefore $u=w+(\mu/2)e=(\pm\sqrt{\mu^2/4+\lambda}+\mu/2)e$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $\mu^2/4+\lambda<0$. Take $z=w/\sqrt{-(\mu^2/4+\lambda)}$. Then $z^2=-e$.

Comment: Correct. Well done, hie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{e,u,u^2\}$ is linearly dependent, so there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $u^2+au+be=0$. If the polynomial $x^2+ax+b$ (with real coefficients) has real roots $r$ and $s$, we have $x^2+ax+b=(x-r)(x-s)$, so
$$
u^2+au+be=(u-re)(u-se)=0
$$
and so either $u-re=0$ or $u-se=0$, which is impossible. Therefore $a^2-4b<0$. Complete the square from $4u^2+4au+4be=0$:
\begin{gather}
4u^2+4au+a^2e-a^2e+4be=0\\[6px]
(2u+ae)^2=(a^2-4b)e
\end{gather}
Can you finish?